# How can we calculate" $(\frac{\partial x}{\partial z})_w$"

Tags: calculus

Given the equations  $F(x,y,z,w)=0$ and $G(x,y,z,w)=0$ . Where $F$ and $G$ have continuous first partial derivatives,  $(\frac{\partial x}{\partial z})_w$= ?

I think this question was asked earlier.But I do not understand anything from the answers.I tried to solve.I obtained this part.I think $x$ and $y$ are depend and $z$,$w$ are independent by theorem then

$F_1 (\frac{\partial x}{\partial z})$$+$$F_2 (\frac{\partial y}{\partial z})$$+$$F_3$=$0$

$G_1 (\frac{\partial x}{\partial z})$$+$$G_2 (\frac{\partial y}{\partial z})$$+$$G_3$=$0$

$F_4 (\frac{\partial w}{\partial z})$ and $G_4 (\frac{\partial w}{\partial z})$$
not important because w is independent.

How can I continue ?

Comment: What do you mean by the notation $\left(\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial z}\right)_w$? Is it $\dfrac{d^2x}{dwdz}$ ?

Comment: no. it is systems of equations by implicit functions

Comment: So what is $\left(\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial z}\right)_w$?

Comment: Its the derivative of x with respect to z keeping w constant I think, I feel its more common in physics (like in thermodynamics) to explicitly mention the variable being kept constant. From what I gather x doesn't depend on y?

Comment: not physics of course the  physics depend on calculus  but it is question of calculus.actually i  can use cramer rule but i don't do it .it is complicated